# log-likelihood function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood

There are 3 classified groups with the numbers being $n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}$. According to the genetic model, the probabilities for each group are proportional to:
$p_{1}(\theta):p_{2}(\theta):p_{3}(\theta) = (1-\theta):(1+2\theta):(1-\theta)$ where $\theta > 0$ is an unknown parameter. 
A multinomial sample for the three categories is available with $n_{1} = 31, n_{2}=47, n_{3}=22$.

$n=n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}=100$.

I need to find the log-likelihood for these data.

Not sure how to do this since they are given as a proportion. How would it differ from the 'normal' way of finding the log-likelihood function?

Comment: From the fact the probabilities must sum to $1$ you can work them out explicitly if you feel the need.  For most purposes the log-likelihood needs to be known only up to an additive constant that can be absorbed in this normalization.

Comment: Thanks! managed to figure it out

Comment: The normalisation does not matter in this case because the normalising constant (equal to 3) does not depend on $\theta$.